# atexit: How does one trigger it manually?

Tags: python, airflow, atexit

When I run a python script, I can exit the interpreter and `atexit` will execute all the functions I have registered.

Now, I am using airflow and would like to trigger `atexit` tasks `on_kill()` (i.e., when I clear out or kill a dag node in airflow).

For example, in pseudo code, I need to be able to:

```
class Foo(PythonOperator):
  ...
  def on_kill():
     # somehow, trigger atexit tasks without exiting the 
     # process entirely
```

`atexit` isn't a necessity either--I could do something else.  The major point is that something getting executed outside the context of python needs to be killed in a procedural manner, and ideally passing up the kill function by reference to the housing script would be a last resort (python does not make this particular alternative easy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could monkey-patch the `atexit` module — something like this:

```
import atexit
from queue import LifoQueue


save_register = atexit.register
atexit_queue = LifoQueue()

def my_register(func, *args, **kwargs):
    save_register(func, *args, **kwargs)
    atexit_queue.put((func, args, kwargs))

atexit.register = my_register


if __name__ == '__main__':

    def func1():
        print('func1() called')

    def func2(arg):
        print(f'func2({arg}) called')

    def func3(arg, kwarg1=1, kwarg2='foo'):
        print(f'func3({arg}, kwarg1={kwarg1}, kwarg2={kwarg2!r}) called')

    atexit.register(func1)
    atexit.register(func2, 1)
    atexit.register(func3, 2, kwarg1=42, kwarg2='bar')

    print('Calling queued atexit functions:\n')
    while atexit_queue.qsize():
        func, args, kwargs = atexit_queue.get()
        atexit.unregister(func)  # Prevent it from being called again.
        func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Output:

```
Calling queued atexit functions:

func3(2, kwarg1=42, kwarg2='bar') called
func2(1) called
func1() called
```

Comment: That’s brilliant

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not misunderstanding your question, you can trigger all functions registered in `atexit` via `atexit._run_exitfuncs()`:

```
import atexit


def do_something():
    print('I am doing some work')


def run_on_exit():
    print('I run on exit')


def do_something_else():
    print('I am doing more work')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    atexit.register(run_on_exit)
    do_something()
    atexit._run_exitfuncs()
    do_something_else()
```

The output reveals that triggering the registered exit function will not stop the program flow but allow for running further functions.